# Mongoose populate virtual with sort and limit

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to write a mongoose query that retrieves a group of assets along with the most recent transactions for those assets.  The transactions are in a separate collection from the assets.

To accomplish this, first I created a virtual array in the asset model to link the assets to the transactions.

```
schema.virtual('transactions', {
    ref: 'transaction',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: '_asset',
    justOne: false
})
```

Then I query using .populate in an node.js express controller (note the hard-coded "limit: 1" will become N at some point):

```
exports.getList = function (req, res) {
    Model
        .find({}, { __v: 0 })
        .populate({
            path: 'transactions',
            options: { sort: { 'created_at': -1}, limit: 1},
        })
        .lean()
        .exec(function (err, model) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(model);
        });
  }
```

With 3 assets in my test system and a bunch of transactions for each one, it is returning old transactions for the first two assets and nothing for the third one.

When I remove the "limit:1" and return all transactions, it sorts properly and returns transactions for all three assets.

I believe I am running into this bug:

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4321

**Any ideas on an elegant workaround?

Returning all transactions will not be a viable long-term solution.**

Comment: If you really want the "latest" to always be returned then you could always "update" that way using [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/#up._S_sort) or [`$position`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/#up._S_position) in the first place. Then you can simply "query" using [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) in projection.

Comment: The benefits there are that even with the "options" on `.populate()` the initial "query" **still** actually returns the whole array anyway. If you actually "update" that way, and then `$slice`, then **only** the "latest" is actually returned in the query. So `.populate()` does not work how you seem to think it does to "limit" in this case.

Comment: Actually looking again I notice the `.virtual()` there, which adds to the problem. The sort of results you appear to be expecting would only be possible where the "related" data was queried via `.aggregate()` instead, since it's *"the last for each parent _asset"*, and that's an "aggregation". The `.populate()` method does not do that, nor does the current release MongoDB is a workable way. Your use case may be better suited here actually keeping the "most recent transactions" within an actual array of the parent, rather than "just" a virtual property.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a curly issue indeed. The basics here is that `.populate()` and certainly not "populate with virtuals",  is not designed to work like you are expecting here.

### Issue Explained

In essence `.populate()` is essentially another query issued to MongoDB to retrieve related data. For this it basically issues a query with [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) containing all of the "related field" values for the target to match on.

What is at the core of the ["issue 4321"](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4321) is that with such options as `"sort"` and `"limit"` the actual query that needs to be provided with such an [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) argument is in fact an `.aggregate()` statement that would be able to *"get the last `n` results grouped for each key"*. This is not actually what mongoose presently issues to MongoDB, nor is it really practical to group `n` items by available operations at this time.

You can work around that using `.aggregate()` manually, as demonstrated at the end of the provided listing, but of course only practically in a limited number of cases.

```
  // Get latest transactions for each master
  Transaction.aggregate([
    { '$match': {
      '_asset': {
        '$in': masters.map(m => m._id)
      }
    }},
    { '$sort': { '_asset': 1, 'createdAt': -1 } },
    { '$group': {
      '_id': '$_asset',
      'amount': { '$first': '$amount' },
      'createdAt': { '$first': '$createdAt' },
      'updatedAt': { '$first': '$updatedAt' },
      'did': { '$first': '$_id' }
    }},
    { '$project': {
      '_id': '$did',
      '_asset': '$_id',
      'amount': 1,
      'createdAt': 1,
      'updatedAt': 1
    }}
  ])
```

It's not great and not a really performant solution, but better than other similar alternatives. There is I believe though a still better way.

### A Better Solution

For your case here, and I would suspect many similar cases, you don't want to include the "full" transactions list within the parent documents even as references due to the potential size of the arrays produced. This sort of "anti-pattern" is generally what "virtual populate" and indeed `$lookup` are designed to avoid.

In your particular use case of *"get the latest transaction"* though, neither of those are a viable solution. Since both would essentially require looking at "all" transactions and then only retrieving `n` results from them.

So the "latest" or indeed the "most recent" cases here actually falls back to "embedding" ( at least references ) at a "limited number" in order to provide a workable solution. So the proposal is to do exactly that, and keep a `"recent"` list of transactions within the parent itself. This gives you a document in the scenario included that looks like:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32661"),
        "__v" : 0,
        "name" : "One",
        "recent" : [
                ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32676"),
                ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32674"),
                ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32672"),
                ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32670"),
                ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a3266e")
        ]
}
```

Noting here that these are not "all" the related transactions but just the "most recent" ones. The point is to only keep a "small" list as appropriate to the purpose.

In this way, you can directly query the "parent" and just [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) off the array contained for the `"recent"` items. In the listing I do this as:

```
Master.find().select({ 'recent': { '$slice': 1 } })
```

That returns the "latest" entry from the array without any other query to the server. It's the "latest" in this case, because instead we "prepend" items to this array at the same time as we write to the `"transactions"` collection, which has everything:

```
Transaction.create({ _asset: master._id, amount: data.amount })
  .then(transaction =>
    Master.update(
      { _id: transaction._asset },
      { "$push": {
        "recent": {
          "$each": [transaction._id],
          "$position": 0,
          "$slice": 5
        }
      }}
    )
```

The key element there is the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) to the array in the parent which is modified with the [`$position`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) to "preprend" at the beginning of the array so the "first" item is always the "latest" transaction to be added related to the parent.

Then the [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/) modifier is used here to keep the `"recent"` array to a limit of `n` items only. So the "oldest" items will be "pushed off" the list as newer items are added.

There is then in addition another practical purpose here that when listing the "master" and "transactions" in a paging scenario, the first request can use the `"recent"` array directly. Then additional request for new "pages", can simply filter out the items contained within the `"recent"` array via [`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) and use the regular `.skip()` and `.limit()` or alternate "range" paging practice to retrieve each "page" of results.

To demonstrate all concepts in full, see the listing and all the generated results below.

**Demonstration listing:**

```
const async = require('async'),
      mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.set('debug',true);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/prepend');

const transactionSchema = new Schema({
  _asset: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Master' },
  amount: Number
},{
  timestamps: {
    createdAt: 'createdAt'
  }
});


const Transaction = mongoose.model('Transaction', transactionSchema);

const masterSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  recent: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Transaction' }]
});

masterSchema.virtual('transactions', {
  ref: 'Transaction',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: '_asset',
  justOne: false
});


const Master = mongoose.model('Master', masterSchema);

function log(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2))
}

async.series(
  [
    // Clean data
    (callback) =>
      async.each(mongoose.models,(model,callback) =>
        model.remove({},callback),callback),

    // Create Masters
    (callback) =>
      Master.insertMany(['One','Two'].map( name => ({ name })),callback),

    // Add 10 transactions to each master
    (callback) =>
      async.each(['One','Two'],(name,callback) =>
        async.eachSeries(
          Array.apply(null,Array(10)).map((e,i) => ({ name, amount: i+1 })),
          (data,callback) => {
            Master.findOne({ name: data.name })
              .then(master =>
                Transaction.create({ _asset: master._id, amount: data.amount })
              )
              .then(transaction =>
                Master.update(
                  { _id: transaction._asset },
                  { "$push": {
                    "recent": {
                      "$each": [transaction._id],
                      "$position": 0,
                      "$slice": 5
                    }
                  }}
                )
              )
              .then(res => callback())
              .catch(callback)
          },
          callback
        ),
      callback),

    // Show populated recent 1 entry only
    (callback) =>
      Master.find().select({ 'recent': { '$slice': 1 } })
        .populate('recent').exec((err,results) => {
        if (err) callback(err);
        log(results);
        callback();
      }),

    // Populate recent - page 1 then fetch next page
    (callback) =>
      async.waterfall(
        [
          (callback) =>
            Master.findOne({ name: 'One' }).populate('recent')
              .lean()
              .exec((err,master) => {
                if (err) callback(err);
                log(master);
                callback(null,{
                  _asset: master._id,
                  exclude: master.recent.map( r => r._id )
                });
              }),

          (options,callback) =>
            Transaction.find({
              _asset: options._asset,
              _id: { '$nin': options.exclude }
            }).sort({ 'createdAt': -1 }).limit(5)
            .exec((err,transactions) => {
              if (err) callback(err);
              log(transactions)
              callback();
            })

        ],
        callback
      ),

    // Issue 4321 - Fix - Manual populate with aggregate
    (callback) =>
      Master.find().select('-recent').exec()
        .then(masters => {
          // Get latest transactions for each master
          Transaction.aggregate([
            { '$match': {
              '_asset': {
                '$in': masters.map(m => m._id)
              }
            }},
            { '$sort': { '_asset': 1, 'createdAt': -1 } },
            { '$group': {
              '_id': '$_asset',
              'amount': { '$first': '$amount' },
              'createdAt': { '$first': '$createdAt' },
              'updatedAt': { '$first': '$updatedAt' },
              'did': { '$first': '$_id' }
            }},
            { '$project': {
              '_id': '$did',
              '_asset': '$_id',
              'amount': 1,
              'createdAt': 1,
              'updatedAt': 1
            }}
          ]).exec((err,transactions) => {
            // Map latest transactions to master
            masters = masters.map(
              m => Object.assign(
                m.toObject(),
                {
                  transactions: transactions.filter(
                    t => t._asset.toHexString() === m._id.toHexString()
                  )
                }
              )
            );

            log(masters);
            callback();
          })
        }).catch(callback)

  ],
  (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

**Demonstration Output**

```
Mongoose: transactions.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: masters.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: masters.insertMany([ { __v: 0, name: 'One', _id: 5959e34adf833e1451a32661, recent: [] }, { __v: 0, name: 'Two', _id: 5959e34adf833e1451a32662, recent: [] } ], null)
Mongoose: masters.findOne({ name: 'One' }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: masters.findOne({ name: 'Two' }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: transactions.insert({ updatedAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:14 GMT"), createdAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:14 GMT"), _asset: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32662"), amount: 1, _id: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32663"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: transactions.insert({ updatedAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), createdAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), _asset: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32661"), amount: 1, _id: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32664"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: masters.update({ _id: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32661") }, { '$push': { recent: { '$each': [ ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32664") ], '$slice': 5, '$position': 0 } } }, {})
Mongoose: masters.update({ _id: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32662") }, { '$push': { recent: { '$each': [ ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32663") ], '$slice': 5, '$position': 0 } } }, {})
Mongoose: masters.findOne({ name: 'One' }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: masters.findOne({ name: 'Two' }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: transactions.insert({ updatedAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), createdAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), _asset: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32662"), amount: 2, _id: ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32665"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: transactions.insert({ updatedAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), createdAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), _asset: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32661"), amount: 2, _id: ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32666"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: masters.update({ _id: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32661") }, { '$push': { recent: { '$each': [ ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32666") ], '$slice': 5, '$position': 0 } } }, {})
Mongoose: masters.update({ _id: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32662") }, { '$push': { recent: { '$each': [ ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32665") ], '$slice': 5, '$position': 0 } } }, {})
Mongoose: masters.findOne({ name: 'One' }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: masters.findOne({ name: 'Two' }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: transactions.insert({ updatedAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), createdAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), _asset: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32662"), amount: 3, _id: ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32667"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: transactions.insert({ updatedAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), createdAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), _asset: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32661"), amount: 3, _id: ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32668"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: masters.update({ _id: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32661") }, { '$push': { recent: { '$each': [ ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32668") ], '$slice': 5, '$position': 0 } } }, {})
Mongoose: masters.update({ _id: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32662") }, { '$push': { recent: { '$each': [ ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32667") ], '$slice': 5, '$position': 0 } } }, {})
Mongoose: masters.findOne({ name: 'One' }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: masters.findOne({ name: 'Two' }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: transactions.insert({ updatedAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), createdAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), _asset: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32662"), amount: 4, _id: ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32669"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: transactions.insert({ updatedAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), createdAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), _asset: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32661"), amount: 4, _id: ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a3266a"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: masters.update({ _id: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32661") }, { '$push': { recent: { '$each': [ ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a3266a") ], '$slice': 5, '$position': 0 } } }, {})
Mongoose: masters.update({ _id: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32662") }, { '$push': { recent: { '$each': [ ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32669") ], '$slice': 5, '$position': 0 } } }, {})
Mongoose: masters.findOne({ name: 'One' }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: masters.findOne({ name: 'Two' }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: transactions.insert({ updatedAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), createdAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), _asset: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32662"), amount: 5, _id: ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a3266b"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: transactions.insert({ updatedAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), createdAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), _asset: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32661"), amount: 5, _id: ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a3266c"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: masters.update({ _id: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32661") }, { '$push': { recent: { '$each': [ ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a3266c") ], '$slice': 5, '$position': 0 } } }, {})
Mongoose: masters.update({ _id: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32662") }, { '$push': { recent: { '$each': [ ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a3266b") ], '$slice': 5, '$position': 0 } } }, {})
Mongoose: masters.findOne({ name: 'One' }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: masters.findOne({ name: 'Two' }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: transactions.insert({ updatedAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), createdAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), _asset: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32662"), amount: 6, _id: ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a3266d"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: transactions.insert({ updatedAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), createdAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), _asset: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32661"), amount: 6, _id: ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a3266e"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: masters.update({ _id: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32661") }, { '$push': { recent: { '$each': [ ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a3266e") ], '$slice': 5, '$position': 0 } } }, {})
Mongoose: masters.update({ _id: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32662") }, { '$push': { recent: { '$each': [ ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a3266d") ], '$slice': 5, '$position': 0 } } }, {})
Mongoose: masters.findOne({ name: 'One' }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: masters.findOne({ name: 'Two' }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: transactions.insert({ updatedAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), createdAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), _asset: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32662"), amount: 7, _id: ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a3266f"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: transactions.insert({ updatedAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), createdAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), _asset: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32661"), amount: 7, _id: ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32670"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: masters.update({ _id: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32661") }, { '$push': { recent: { '$each': [ ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32670") ], '$slice': 5, '$position': 0 } } }, {})
Mongoose: masters.update({ _id: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32662") }, { '$push': { recent: { '$each': [ ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a3266f") ], '$slice': 5, '$position': 0 } } }, {})
Mongoose: masters.findOne({ name: 'One' }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: masters.findOne({ name: 'Two' }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: transactions.insert({ updatedAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), createdAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), _asset: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32662"), amount: 8, _id: ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32671"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: transactions.insert({ updatedAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), createdAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), _asset: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32661"), amount: 8, _id: ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32672"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: masters.update({ _id: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32661") }, { '$push': { recent: { '$each': [ ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32672") ], '$slice': 5, '$position': 0 } } }, {})
Mongoose: masters.update({ _id: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32662") }, { '$push': { recent: { '$each': [ ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32671") ], '$slice': 5, '$position': 0 } } }, {})
Mongoose: masters.findOne({ name: 'One' }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: masters.findOne({ name: 'Two' }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: transactions.insert({ updatedAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), createdAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), _asset: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32662"), amount: 9, _id: ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32673"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: transactions.insert({ updatedAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), createdAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), _asset: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32661"), amount: 9, _id: ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32674"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: masters.update({ _id: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32661") }, { '$push': { recent: { '$each': [ ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32674") ], '$slice': 5, '$position': 0 } } }, {})
Mongoose: masters.update({ _id: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32662") }, { '$push': { recent: { '$each': [ ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32673") ], '$slice': 5, '$position': 0 } } }, {})
Mongoose: masters.findOne({ name: 'One' }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: masters.findOne({ name: 'Two' }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: transactions.insert({ updatedAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), createdAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), _asset: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32662"), amount: 10, _id: ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32675"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: transactions.insert({ updatedAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), createdAt: new Date("Mon, 03 Jul 2017 06:25:15 GMT"), _asset: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32661"), amount: 10, _id: ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32676"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: masters.update({ _id: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32661") }, { '$push': { recent: { '$each': [ ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32676") ], '$slice': 5, '$position': 0 } } }, {})
Mongoose: masters.update({ _id: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32662") }, { '$push': { recent: { '$each': [ ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32675") ], '$slice': 5, '$position': 0 } } }, {})
Mongoose: masters.find({}, { fields: { recent: { '$slice': 1 } } })
Mongoose: transactions.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32676"), ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32675") ] } }, { fields: {} })
[
  {
    "_id": "5959e34adf833e1451a32661",
    "__v": 0,
    "name": "One",
    "recent": [
      {
        "_id": "5959e34bdf833e1451a32676",
        "updatedAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.282Z",
        "createdAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.282Z",
        "_asset": "5959e34adf833e1451a32661",
        "amount": 10,
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5959e34adf833e1451a32662",
    "__v": 0,
    "name": "Two",
    "recent": [
      {
        "_id": "5959e34bdf833e1451a32675",
        "updatedAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.280Z",
        "createdAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.280Z",
        "_asset": "5959e34adf833e1451a32662",
        "amount": 10,
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
Mongoose: masters.findOne({ name: 'One' }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: transactions.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32676"), ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32674"), ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32672"), ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32670"), ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a3266e") ] } }, { fields: {} })
{
  "_id": "5959e34adf833e1451a32661",
  "__v": 0,
  "name": "One",
  "recent": [
    {
      "_id": "5959e34bdf833e1451a32676",
      "updatedAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.282Z",
      "createdAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.282Z",
      "_asset": "5959e34adf833e1451a32661",
      "amount": 10,
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5959e34bdf833e1451a32674",
      "updatedAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.264Z",
      "createdAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.264Z",
      "_asset": "5959e34adf833e1451a32661",
      "amount": 9,
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5959e34bdf833e1451a32672",
      "updatedAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.216Z",
      "createdAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.216Z",
      "_asset": "5959e34adf833e1451a32661",
      "amount": 8,
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5959e34bdf833e1451a32670",
      "updatedAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.195Z",
      "createdAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.195Z",
      "_asset": "5959e34adf833e1451a32661",
      "amount": 7,
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5959e34bdf833e1451a3266e",
      "updatedAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.180Z",
      "createdAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.180Z",
      "_asset": "5959e34adf833e1451a32661",
      "amount": 6,
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
Mongoose: transactions.find({ _id: { '$nin': [ ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32676"), ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32674"), ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32672"), ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a32670"), ObjectId("5959e34bdf833e1451a3266e") ] }, _asset: ObjectId("5959e34adf833e1451a32661") }, { sort: { createdAt: -1 }, limit: 5, fields: {} })
[
  {
    "_id": "5959e34bdf833e1451a3266c",
    "updatedAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.164Z",
    "createdAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.164Z",
    "_asset": "5959e34adf833e1451a32661",
    "amount": 5,
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5959e34bdf833e1451a3266a",
    "updatedAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.135Z",
    "createdAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.135Z",
    "_asset": "5959e34adf833e1451a32661",
    "amount": 4,
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5959e34bdf833e1451a32668",
    "updatedAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.080Z",
    "createdAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.080Z",
    "_asset": "5959e34adf833e1451a32661",
    "amount": 3,
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5959e34bdf833e1451a32666",
    "updatedAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.039Z",
    "createdAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.039Z",
    "_asset": "5959e34adf833e1451a32661",
    "amount": 2,
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5959e34adf833e1451a32664",
    "updatedAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.009Z",
    "createdAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.009Z",
    "_asset": "5959e34adf833e1451a32661",
    "amount": 1,
    "__v": 0
  }
]
Mongoose: masters.find({}, { fields: { recent: 0 } })
Mongoose: transactions.aggregate([ { '$match': { _asset: { '$in': [ 5959e34adf833e1451a32661, 5959e34adf833e1451a32662 ] } } }, { '$sort': { _asset: 1, createdAt: -1 } }, { '$group': { _id: '$_asset', amount: { '$first': '$amount' }, createdAt: { '$first': '$createdAt' }, updatedAt: { '$first': '$updatedAt' }, did: { '$first': '$_id' } } }, { '$project': { _id: '$did', _asset: '$_id', amount: 1, createdAt: 1, updatedAt: 1 } } ], {})
[
  {
    "_id": "5959e34adf833e1451a32661",
    "__v": 0,
    "name": "One",
    "transactions": [
      {
        "amount": 10,
        "createdAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.282Z",
        "updatedAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.282Z",
        "_id": "5959e34bdf833e1451a32676",
        "_asset": "5959e34adf833e1451a32661"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5959e34adf833e1451a32662",
    "__v": 0,
    "name": "Two",
    "transactions": [
      {
        "amount": 10,
        "createdAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.280Z",
        "updatedAt": "2017-07-03T06:25:15.280Z",
        "_id": "5959e34bdf833e1451a32675",
        "_asset": "5959e34adf833e1451a32662"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Neil, WOW! Thank you for the amazing response!  You clearly put some time into it.  The other solutions I had contemplated would have been barbaric compared to this.

Comment: @hoekma This is actually a "cut down" example of  a ["Hybrid Schema"](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-comments/#hybrid-schema-design) which is briefly touched on in the linked core documentation topic. IMHO it's a wise pattern for high volume relations where the most common requests are to "recent data". So I'm demonstrating by example what I touched on with the initial comments on the question. Being that where there is a "recent" array present, you can use that data, and only go to the additional "full source" when actually requested. It's the most common case.

Answer (score 9):

For those reading this in 2021, as of `mongoose 5.12.3` following can be done in model:

```js
schema.virtual('transactions', {
    ref: 'transaction',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: '_asset',
    justOne: false,
    options: { sort: { 'createdAt': -1}, limit: 1},
})
```

Then in controller:

```js
exports.getList = function (req, res) {
    Model
        .find({})
        .populate({
            path: 'transactions',
        })
        .lean()
        .exec(function (err, model) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(model);
        });
  }
```