# MongoDB: How to get data by join

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having following two schemas in mongodb

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  first_name:  String,
  last_name: String,
  email:   String
});

var messageSchema = new Schema({
  sender: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' },
  receiver: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' },
  message: String,
  sentOn:   Date,
});

var Users = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);
var Messages = mongoose.model('messages', messageSchema);
```

How can I query to get the all users from 'users' collection and their last message (single) from 'messages' collection?

Comment: You probably really want to structure around this instead by storing the "last" or "last n" message(s) on the `User` itself. See [Mongoose populate virtual with sort and limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44879647/2313887) for a bit more detail. Aside from that MongoDB 3.6 would allow you to effectively do such a `$lookup` result returning only the most recent item, when it is released. Trying to use it now would only work for a very small number of messages, where you effectively need to load everything and then discard all but the latest. See the design points for how to make it better

Comment: Thanks Neil for your comment, I changed the db structure